# Replicate Rotate control functionality

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I’m trying to replicate the Rotate button in the Navigation control but I’ve noticed that when clicking that button, the map doesn’t emit any event (or at least any `moveend`) until you release the mouse button. That makes the rotation more responsive because the app layers are not updated while rotating.

I also noticed that the same behavior happens when clicking and dragging the map. So I looked into the code but I couldn’t find any obvious method that “captures” the events.

In muy button, I capture the input on `mousemove` and update the map’s bearing on every call. But calling `map.setBearing()` triggers an `moveend` every time, which I want to suppress.

Also noticed that when clicking and dragging, or clicking and rotating, there is some inertia applied to the animation, which I cannot reproduce.

Is there any way of replicating that behavior in my custom control?

Comment: Why are you trying to replicate it? Can you just change the behaviour of DragPanHandler instead?

Comment: I guess you mean `DragRotateHandler`? The reason is that I couldn’t find any way of programmatically initiate the action in the handlers. What I want to do is to have my own custom control and when clicked initiate a rotation the same way as the default control does. Is there any way of doing that? If so it would be perfect.